# AWS Amplify mock storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mocking, storage, aws-amplify

I am trying to do a simple `Storage.put` into a mocked S3 bucket.

I have set everything up server-side already.

```
amplify add api
amplify add auth
amplify add storage
```

and I have pushed all of this to AWS and it works fine during testing.

When I run `amplify mock storage` the aws_config files are re-written as they should be to send all requests to the local mock storage and API.

However, inspecting the network requests shows that the mock S3 bucket it hosted on `http://localhost:20005` (no SSL) and the request is sent to `https://localhost:20005` (with SSL)

Even if I run my server with `npm start` or `($env:HTTPS="true") -and (npm start)` it still does not successfuly run the `Storage.put`

The flag in the aws_config file is automatically set so that it should bypass this already:

```
"aws_user_files_s3_dangerously_connect_to_http_endpoint_for_testing": true,
```

The errors I receive are the following:

```
[ERROR] 42:36.732 axios-http-handler Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)

[WARN] 42:36.733 AWSS3Provider - error uploading Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)

Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Run your app without mocking

Look like there are bugs in running `amplify mock` for storage. What I did is as follows:-

1. `amplify push` (Update your local changes to the cloud)
2. Run react native, I am using `expo`, `yarn start` or `expo start`
3. Make sure you're are not running the `amplify mock`.

Note that, when running your app, you're connecting directly to the cloud not with the mock data.

#### Conclusion

The bug might be with the `amplify mock`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app works fine when I run it on normal services. The point I am trying to achieve is to do a bunch of testing on the whole "mock" feature.